# How do I save a .gif file in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, path, python-imaging-library, gif

I keep getting this error:
File "C:\Users\kondi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2300, in save
raise ValueError(f"unknown file extension: {ext}") from e
ValueError: unknown file extension:

In my save_file gui I just want to create the path and then use that path in the make gif function...

```
def make_gif(LIST):
    for each in LIST:
        im = Image.open(each)
        gif_list.append(im)
    gif_list[0].save(save_path, save_all = True, append_images=gif_list[1:], optimize = True, 
duration = play_speed.get(), loop=0)

def save_file():
    files = (
    ("Gif File", "*.gif"),
    ("All files", "*.")
    )
    filenames = asksaveasfile( filetypes = files, defaultextension= "*.gif")
    showinfo(title = "saved path",message = filenames)
    clean_up = str(filenames)
    new_path = clean_up.replace("<_io.TextIOWrapper name=", '').replace(" mode='w' 
encoding='cp1252'>", '')
    save_path = new_path
    make_gif(img_list)
```

I thought the file path from the "Save As" gui would be enough to plug into my make_gif function but it's not working. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Ok fixed it by doing this:

```
def make_gif(LIST, path):
    for each in LIST:
        im = Image.open(each)
        gif_list.append(im)

    gif_list[0].save(
        path,
        save_all=True,
        append_images=gif_list[1:],
        optimize=True,
        duration=play_speed.get(),
        loop=0
   )

def save_file():
    files = (
        ("Gif File", "*.gif"),
        ("All files", "*.")
    )
    filenames = asksaveasfilename(filetypes=files, defaultextension="*.gif")
    showinfo(title="saved path", message=filenames)


    our_path = str(filenames)
    make_gif(img_list, our_path)
```